# How to build Qwt library in debug mode under Linux?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, qmake, qwt, qt5.6

Downloaded qwt-6.1.2.tar.bz2, trying to build under linux:

```
# qmake qwt.pro -r -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
# make
```

Builds libqwt.so.6.1.2 successfully, but I want to build debug libqwt**d**.so.6.1.2 library with d-suffix. Why it is not happening?

Tried release, then debug, debug_and_release, build_all - do not help. What is the problem could be? Or it is different under Linux (I do not see debug info include into lib)?

Comment: have you tried `make -DDEBUG -g`? I make qwt in both debug and release using CMake, and the only qmake command I _ever_ do is `qmake qwt.pro`, so I think the debug libs are comming from the `make` step. I also do the `make install` step.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the build mode is set in `qwtbuild.pri` (from `qwt-6.1.2.tar.bz2`) at line 35. Just change `CONFIG += release` to `CONFIG += debug` and build with:

```
qmake qwt.pro
make
```

Then check the results in the `lib` folder, mine looks like (I renamed `lib` to `lib-release` and `lib-debug`):

```
~/Downloads/qwt-6.1.2$ ls -lsth lib-release/
total 1,7M
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   15 Mai 14 08:05 libqwt.so.6.1 -> libqwt.so.6.1.2
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   15 Mai 14 08:05 libqwt.so -> libqwt.so.6.1.2
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   15 Mai 14 08:05 libqwt.so.6 -> libqwt.so.6.1.2
1,7M -rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 1,7M Mai 14 08:05 libqwt.so.6.1.2

~/Downloads/qwt-6.1.2$ ls -lsth lib-debug/
total 19M
19M -rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 19M Mai 14 10:16 libqwt.so.6.1.2
  0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  15 Mai 14 10:16 libqwt.so.6 -> libqwt.so.6.1.2
  0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  15 Mai 14 10:16 libqwt.so.6.1 -> libqwt.so.6.1.2
  0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  15 Mai 14 10:16 libqwt.so -> libqwt.so.6.1.2
```